# NSDateFormatter showing nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *releaseTime = @"2015-10-30 16:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

NSDate *releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:releaseTime];
```

When i try to access this releaseDate it is showing nil.

Comment: [Date formatter guide for reference](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: [Official apple doc](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the format from `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and it should work.

If you wonder why, `hh` is for am/pm hour format, while `HH` is for 24 hour format. Since you have 16:00:00 it's 24h format and the date formatter can't parse it and returns nil.